# folder permissions so that rsync and move_uploaded_file work

Tags: php, permissions

I've setup a php script that accepts an uploaded file and stores it in `/backend/upload` folder. I am using `move_uploaded_file` to achieve this.

As usual, there were permission issues with `/backend/upload` when working with `move_uploaded_file`. To fix it, I changed the owner of the folder to `apache`. These are my `/backend/upload` permissions:

```
drwxrw----  2 apache myuser 4096 Jan 22 23:35 upload
```

With this permissions I can successfully upload file to the upload folder, but the user `myuser` can't read it. `myuser` group has read and write permissons so it's a little weird that it can't read the folder. What am I missing here?

Now, it's not optimal, but I can live with not seeing the contents of file via `myuser`. What causes more troubles is that `rsycn` now can't upload files, because it does not have permission to access `upload` folder. Root ssh access is disabled.

What do you recommend that I do? Ideally `myuser` would be able to access the `upload` folder, `move_uploaded_file` would be able to upload and rsync would work. I found many answers that suggest using 777 permissions and about the same amount that warn not do go this way.

**ALSO:** I tried to just change the group and owner to this:

```
drwxrw----  2 myuser apache 4096 Jan 22 23:35 upload
```

, but that didn't work for `move_uploaded_file`, even though apache group has read and write permissions.

Comment: Only the owning user has access to it (700), it you want the group to have access (I expect myuser will belong to the myuser group) you want it to be at least 740. `chmod -R 740` on the upload directory might do the trick (OS dependent). Because of rsync, assuming its running on the same user, 760 might be more appropriate to allow the directory to be written to. Dunno.

Comment: myuser belongs to myuser group. I've already set 760 permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the "X' access for directory means to have access to the directory's content.
Check this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862289/difference-between-executable-directory-vs-executable-files
So you have to change the access rights to 770.
Or you set it to 700 leave apache user as owner and when you need to access the content you have o switch to apache user - this suppose to be the safe solution.